# nexus ospf network statement missing

Tags: cisco, routing, ospf, cisco-nexus

In old school `IOS` we used to do

```
router ospf 1
 network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0
```

But in Nexus switch i am not seeing any command or related doc, how do i announce my subnet in ospf in nx-os

My nexus 9k config

```
router ospf 100

interface loopback1
  ip router ospf 100 area 0.0.0.0

interface Ethernet2/11
  ip router ospf 100 area 0.0.0.0
```

Here is my interface config,

```
interface Ethernet2/11
  description Point-to-Point-link-of-ospf
  no switchport
  ip address 10.0.0.10/30
  ip router ospf 100 area 0.0.0.0

interface loopback1
  ip address 74.xx.xx.1/23
  ip router ospf 100 area 0.0.0.0
```

In my neighbor router i am seeing following in my route table

```
R2# sh ip route ospf-100
IP Route Table for VRF "default"
'*' denotes best ucast next-hop
'**' denotes best mcast next-hop
'[x/y]' denotes [preference/metric]
'%<string>' in via output denotes VRF <string>

74.xx.xx.1/32, ubest/mbest: 1/0
    *via 10.0.0.10, Eth2/11, [110/2], 00:08:08, ospf-100, intra
```

Why i am seeing following route `/32` instead of `/23` ????

`74.xx.xx.1/23`  i want to announce this route

Comment: "_how do i announce my subnet in ospf in nx-os_" The network statements do not announce the networks, they tell OSPF which interfaces participate in OSPF. Did you enable OSPF with the `feature ospf` command?

Comment: I did, without that command noway I can run any single ospf command on switch ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cisco routers (and switches) treat loopback interfaces as host routes by default.

You can change this behavior by

```
interface loopback1
ip ospf network point-to-point
```

Comment: Why are you so awesome!!!! :)

Comment: @Satish I can't help it.  I was born this way.

Comment: @Satish The truth is I've been doing this long enough to have made nearly every mistake before.